# Changes in JS files are not reflecting in Node JS Application

Tags: node.js

I'm new in node js and
I'm facing a very confusing problem in my NODE JS express application. I created a contact form and I'm using the Amazone Ubuntu server (aws) to host my application.

Previously, I have another domain name now I have different. I changed all the emails in JS file to send an email on the contact form submit. but my bad luck email still going through old emails even I changed.

here is my code

```
fromEmail="myfromemail@domain.com";
emailto="mytoemail@domain.com";
// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp info',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        user: '', // generated ethereal user
        pass: ''  // generated ethereal password
    }
});



   // setup email data with unicode symbols
let mailOptions = {
    from: 'Domain Name <myfromemail@domain.com >', // sender address
    to: emailto, // list of receivers
    subject: 'Test', // Subject line
    html:"<h1>Test Body</h1>",
};


transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
});
```

guide me how I can solve this issue. If this is due to cache please let me to how I can clear it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by restart app.js on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon), a launcher that watches for changes in code and auto-restart the application.